# Start mysql and apache from cmd

Tags: mysql, apache, batch-file, cmd, xampp

I installed xampp and now I want start apache and mysql from command line and also I won't install services.
I use some command and it's worked but after start mysql (for example) cmd is open, I want close but after close cmd mysql stopped.

Comment: If you close your console, the mysql connection is close. This is normal behavior.

Comment: ok, but I want create batch file to be closed after run

Comment: Then you open your connection. And close it immediately. I recommand to add `pause` at the end of your `.bat` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Either you run it from the command line, having to keep the shell open, or you run it as a service after which you can close cmd (if you used cmd at all).

I would choose the latter, and I can't understand why you won't install it as a service.

Comment: When I run it as a service, start automaticaly on start up and I'm not using theme always even when I set theme start manually. Has any solution for this?

Comment: oh, sorry I mean these(mysql and apache).

Comment: You can set them to be started manually. Personally, I use the [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) installation. Very easy to install, and it also installs an application, which lets you start and stop the services from a system tray icon. I use it myself and find it very convenient, since I also don't use Apache and MySQL all the time. Maybe xampp has a similar feature? Or otherwise you can use `net start` and `net stop` to start and stop services from a batch file.

Comment: Xampp also has a similar feature, but it start on start up. I set these services to manual but it still start on start up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XAMPP, you can start your servers by doing:

> `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start`

Otherwise, you can start your servers with this one:

> `sudo service apache2 start && sudo service mysql start`